# Opening a new window using AJAX

Tags: ajax

Want to open a new windows 640px width and 400px height with the url http://www.google.com when you choose an item in a drop down list without pressing any other button.

I want to get it implemented using the AJAX(XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Try reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open

Comment: I want to get it implemented using the AJAX(XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: What are you trying to load from the server that will be displayed in your new window?

Comment: it will be a simple web url (www.google.com)